# NodeJs Multi-vendor site and product accessing

Tags: node.js

I've been working on a NodeJs web application that uses APi's and a number of differently branded Front-end's for different sellers. Sellers can list their product by visiting appropriate Front-End. However I've hit a problem where there is no logic preventing sellers accessing other seller accounts. 
There are several API's that interact with the product, so an idea was to filter all API's against the seller ID to prevent the wrong seller accessing the wrong product. i.e When Seller A lists a product, an sellerID is recorded against product. So if Seller B tries to access the UpdateProducts API against Seller A product, their Login ID will not match the saved sellerID and it will be denied. I think this will work but checking access against products sounds taxing. Are there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before accessing any data from database every request should be checked if it has token authorization. If token is valid, it is possible to get userId from token and search  any data for the given userId.

P.S. This approach I'm using in REST API